# Feature request for a panel that gives access to previously uploaded attachments

Tags: feature-request, images

Currently I have to search through my older replies to locate an uploaded image in order to reuse the same link in a new reply with relevant content. Reattaching the same image (at least when I can locate it in my  PC) would be an option but it is a waste of server space.
This is particularly useful in Q/A categories like electronics or computers and in general any category that relates to questions that need an attachment (image, file) as part of the reply.

Would it be possible to add a panel where older attachments can be listed/accessed?
Ideally with an option to categorize the attachments in order to browse specific categories when searching.